# indexPath for CGPoint

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I just added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UITableView` but the handler (below) just gives 'null' for `indexPath`.

```
- (void)photoTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
            if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.itemsTableView];
                NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.itemsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
               //...
        }
}
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
 - (void)photoTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
 CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.view convertRect:self.itemsTableView.frame fromView:self.itemsTableView.superview], location))
{
    CGPoint locationInTableview = [self.itemsTableView convertPoint:location fromView:self.view];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.itemsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:locationInTableview];
    if (indexPath) //use this code if needed
        [self tableView:self.itemsTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return;
}

// otherwise proceed with the rest of your gesture handling logic
}
```

Comment: Tried for `UICollectionView`. Works for it perfectly!